# Exporting Mozilla Firefox Bookmarks Into Excel

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

I want to export all the bookmarks from my Firefox browser into CSV or Excel file. How can I do this?

Comment: Just an opinion: I wouldn't export into Excel. I've seen too many users using Excel as a DB. Excel is not a DB, it's a sheet, please keep this in mind. If you want to backup your bookmarks, look for something like XMarks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried the HTML export/excel import option, rather messy but using " as a delimeter on excels text import wizard did get the urls in a useable format - you could then manually zap most of the rest quite easily; rather depends on what you wanted excel to do with the information.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox can export bookmarks as an HTML file, and Excel can open HTML files.

Whether Excel will know what to do with an HTML file with bookmarks is another question. I'll do some puttering around and see if I can get more info.

Comment: Did Excel actually handle this conversion well? I'm actually rather interested. I don't have FF on my work machine to test how well it would work.

Comment: Two downvotes? I appreciate constructive criticism more than hidden stabs.

Answer (score 0):

I did a macro for it, that does 99% of what can be automated.  It's very easy.

. . . maybe you know what Visual Basic command I need to get that extra 1%:

http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/996189-macro-to-convert-my-firefox-27-0-1-bookmarks-to-excel-2010-a.html

[This is the main idea, below. The macro is shown in html at the link above, and two .bas files are there also for download, the one I'm using, and the one that almost does as much as is possible to automate.]

I export my Firefox bookmarks . . . and did this macro to automate it, which I have been doing manually (these are my source notes) . . . I have a question in here, at the pertinent point:

File \ Open \ Desktop \ bookmarks.html Yes . . . Delimited . . . No Tab / Other " . . . Finish View / Arrange All / Horizontal / Ok Zoom to 80% . . . Microsoft Sans Serif . . . 10 point

Highlight columns in yellow ... B - G - I - K - M . . . M is the last column Clear Col A for a sort number index . . . Center the text Delete all of the other non-yellow columns through M Column Width of ... B - C - D - E - F ... to 25

Ctrl+Home . . . Ctrl+F for: "Unsorted" It's always on row 123, unless I add bookmarks that stay there (then I'll have to re-do this macro) There will be a long number in the URL column, right aligned, above these new URLs Highlight Row 123 . . . Shift+Ctrl+Arrow Up . . . Right-click / Delete

Ctrl+Home . . . In Cells A1 and A2, put 1 and 2 Put a sort number index in Col A, drag bottom right corner all the way to 500

Ctrl+End . . . Shift+Home+Ctrl+Home Sort on Col B, the URL, to get rid of spaces

Ctrl+End . . . Home . . Arrow Right . . . Ctrl+Up . . . Arrow down Delete everything that was a space, all the way to the bottom: Shift+Ctrl+Arrow Down+Arrow Down . . . Right-click / Delete This is where the problem lies. The row it finds here will probably be different every time, but the macro keeps the row that was determined, when making the macro. Is there a command, like "last active cell" ? If I leave this part out of the macro, I get the data I want, it's just messy, because I have numbers in Col A, and my URLs are not in the original order done. The example here is for 25 bookmarks. If I try to process a bookmarks.html file of 23 bookmarks, it leaves an extra 2 random lines. If I try to process a bookmarks.html file of 11 bookmarks, it leaves an extra 14 random lines. Ctrl+End . . . Shift+Home+Ctrl+Home Sort on Col A, the index, to put URLs back in the original order

Ctrl+Home Put URLs of Col B to the right of the web page names

Ctrl+Home Ctrl+H . . . replace . . . ">" . . . and . . . "

. . . with nothing

Unhighlight B - C - D Ctrl+Home

```
            Manual editing part (when I leave out the above issue)
```

Run the Macro: Process_Bookmarks Sort on Col A, the index, to put URLs back in the order done Move some Titles from B - C - D . . . to E Sorting on B - C - D can make it easier to get them Un-highlight all

Copy and Paste links to bottom of Favorites / Take a look at them to verify / SAVE Close / Dont' Save the Import Edit the bookmark Titles for special characters, or go back to web page to get the Title of the page / then categorize Delete bookmarks.html on Desktop, and the Unsorted URLs in Firefox bookmarks.html will remain in the Recycle Bin for a day or so, in case there are any problems

Comment: Please answer the question on this site instead of linking to another site.

Comment: I can't get my info into this area, and really want to share this, it works great . . . I would like to kindly refer you to check out #5 on this page:

http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/996189-macro-to-convert-my-firefox-27-0-1-bookmarks-to-excel-2010-a.html

This is my updated version of the steps for the Macro, it works a little better.  TY.